# How to cut a mesh in blender? like people do in C4d

Tags: texturing, soft-body

I wanna slice a mesh, like a thread or knife is cutting it.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=db1wvTkVxTY {watch it from 0:40 to 0:50.}

[image: cheese wire cutting cylinder]

Please help

Comment: I've just scribbled trough this overly long tutorial, but he is not using soft body. You should provide more information in your question, provide screenshots, gifs, etc. and do not rely on outside source. Also, one question at a time.

Comment: @ 0:40 in the video, i want to recreate that in blender, how can i do that? (Slicing water melong like thing with a string) & sorry, i just started learning blender, i dont know most of its technical terms.

Comment: You can fake all the physics of the action of a cheese wire slicing a cylinder and the resulting slice peeling off. See how far you get with a Curve modifier and an animated Bezier Curve.